# If $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, show that $m^{φ(n)} + n^{φ(m)} ≡ 1 \mod{mn}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

> If $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, show that $m^{φ(n)} + n^{φ(m)} ≡ 1 \mod {mn}$

The only similar problem I found to this in my notes was "Find all positive integers $n$ such that $φ(n) = 12$." Unfortunately this was no help and I'm really lost, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, you know from Euler-Fermat that
$$
m^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}
$$
and, similarly,
$$
n^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{m}
$$
Since $n^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 0\pmod{n}$, we also have
$$
m^{\varphi(n)}+n^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1+0\pmod{n}
$$
and, similarly,
$$
m^{\varphi(n)}+n^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1+0\pmod{m}
$$
Now use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Or use the following property (and the definition of mod): $$a,b\mid n\iff \text{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}\mid n$$